# A Measurable Function is the Pointwise Limits (a.e.) of a Sequence of Cont. Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be a measurable set. If $f : E \to \Bbb{R}$ is a measurable function, then there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of continuous functions $E$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. on $E$.

I think I have a proof; but I am wondering if someone would critique it.

> For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, Lusin's theorem tells us that there exists a continuous function $f_n : E \to \Bbb{R}$ and a closed set $F_n \subseteq E$ such that $f=f_n$ on $F_n$ and $m(E \setminus F_n) < \frac{1}{2^n}$. Let $E_n := \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty F_k$, so $E_n$ is a closed set and therefore measurable. It isn't difficult to show that $\{E \setminus E_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a decreasing sequence of measurable sets and that $E - E_1$ is of finite measure. Hence, 
>   $$m(E \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n) = m \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty (E \setminus E_n) \right)$$
>
> $$= \lim_{n \to \infty} m(E \setminus E_n)$$
>
> $$= \lim_{n \to \infty} m \left(\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty (E \setminus F_k) \right)$$
>
> $$ \le \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty m(E \setminus F_k)$$
>
> $$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{n=k}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$$
>
> $$=0$$
>
> This shows that $E \setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ is a set of measure $0$. Moreover, if $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, then there exists some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x \in F_k$ for every $k \ge n$. This means that $f_k(x) = f(x)$ for every $k \ge n$, so $\lim_{k \to \infty} f_k(x) = f(x)$. Therefore, $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. on $E$

How does this look?

Comment: Looks correct to me.